# como corregir una archivo .csv que no tiene separados los valores numéricos y los lee como una sola variable

Tags: r, csv

Creé muchos archivos de la siguiente manera:

```
write.table(spec_h_sp, file = "wag004.csv", sep = ""),
```

El error fue que en la función `sep`, no le agregué ningún símbolo para separar los valores numéricos por eso me los lee como un solo valor

Me lee todos los valores decimales y numéricos como una sola variable pero son 28,
¿como hacer para que cuando abra el archivo en `R` me lo lea todas los valores numéricos en columnas independientes?

Todos los valores numéricos se encuentran en una sola variable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: está complicado, pero un par de ideas: si la parte entera siempre tiene 2 dígitos, cortar por 2 dígitos antes del separador de decimales(.) , si la parte decimal tiene x dígitos hacer el corte luego de x dígitos luego del separador de decimales

Comment: Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y agrega un ejemplo con algunas filas del archivo, no como imagen sino como texto

Comment: Utiliza `read.fwf("wag004.csv", widths = c(20,40,60, ....))` donde `widths` son las posiciones donde empieza el siguiente número.